# Use env variable in makefile target

Tags: make

I am trying to figure out how to use env variables in makefiles. I have (kind of) specific use-case where I need to do these steps:

1. run command1
2. assign output form command2 to env variable
3. run command3 which read env variable assigned in step 2

This is the makefile implementing the steps described above. However, when I run it prints an empty variable. What am I doing wrong? When I run these commands in my bash it works just fine)

```
test:
    @bash -c "\
        echo 'need to run some program before assigning env variable';\
        export TEST="$(date)";\
        echo 'printing env';\
        echo ${TEST};\
        "
```

Comment: Inside a Makefile you need to double every dollar sign that you want to be given to the shell.

Comment: That doesn't work either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dollar signs are used by make, so you need to escape them if you want them passed to the shell. You do this by doubling them.

```
test:
        @bash -c "\
        echo 'need to run some program before assigning env variable';\
        echo 'The make CC variable is set to :${CC}:';\
        export TEST=\"\$$(date)\";\
        echo 'printing env';\
        echo \$${TEST};\
        "

testwithout:
        @echo 'need to run some program before assigning env variable';\
        echo 'The make CC variable is set to :${CC}:';\
        export TEST="$$(date)";\
        echo 'printing env';\
        echo $${TEST};
```

The other problems are caused by interpreting the string twice. `make` takes the recipie, converts the sequence backslash newline, and gives the result to the shell to execute. As you are using double quotes for your `bash -c " .... "` this results in the shell expanding the dollar signs, so you end up with `bash -c "echo 'need ...' ;export TEST=Mon Sep...; echo ;". Adding some backslash characters protects the dollar signs and the interior double quotes.

There is probably no need to use the `bash -c`. as shown in the testwithout target. You will still need to construct the command as one line. Gnu make has a `.ONESHELL` facility to use a single shell to execute a recipe rather than one shell per logical line, which allows you to avoid the contortions.

Comment: sadly it doesn't work for me... When I run `make test` I see output only from the first two echos

Comment: Thanks.Also double quotes needs to be escaped. `export TEST=\"\$$(date)\";\`. Apart from that it works just fine :)

Comment: expanded answer and added escaping of the double quotes.